# Can't insert sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api

I get the error message: "Specified sheet must be part of the spreadsheet".  I assume the "specified sheet" is the sourceSheet... but who knows.  What is this trying to tell me?  Better yet, how do I fix it?  I want to insert a sheet from spreadsheet "File1", into spreadsheet "File2".

Thank you

```
function copyTemplate() {

  var targetID="0Atn-Fxxxxt5YdF9VVxxxxxxxlZlVmeXoxxxzJuQ3c";

  // The code below will duplicate the sheet named "CellData" and insert it after 
  // the 1st sheet and call it "CellData"

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CellData");

  var targetFile=SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetID);  

  targetFile.insertSheet("CellData", 1, {template:sourceSheet});   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function copyTemplate() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CellData')
  .copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Atn-Fxxxxt5YdF9VVxxxxxxxlZlVmeXoxxxzJuQ3c'));
}
```